# How can i change textbox text to string variable and send it another class and use it in sendkey

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

i want  textbox text convert to string variable and send it another class and use it in sendkey

```
public void ScreenshotOfElement()
    {

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://allcoins.pw/");
   driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='captchal']")).SendKeys(str);

    }

   private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = textBox1.Text;
    }
```

Comment: `textBox1.Text` is already a string. no need to convert it. Pull your `string str` variable out of that button click event and put it directly into the form class. That way you can access it in your `ScreenshotOfElement` method (if it is in the same class).
Read a bit about 'variable scope' and you will understand what is wrong with your code. This is essential to understand!

Comment: why not pass it as an argument to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few changes in your funtion as below:

```
 public string Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = textBox1.Text;
        return str;
    }
```

Assuming you get your String already as **Text** function return String itself. if it is not printing your `str` value, if you not getting result there is issue with your locator.

You need to change function from **private** to **public** as you need this output in another class, if function remain private you can't call it outside the class.

you also need to change the return parameter of function from void to String. otherwise where ever you call function it will return you nothing.

add the keyword return in function where you got the text or required result.

Now you just need t create an object of your class and call the function as it is non static .

You can do it like below:

Assuming your class name is obj

```
Obj obj= new Obj();
obj.Button1_Click(PARA1,PARA2)
```